# Why cant set pointers in functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have noticed that if i create a pointer in a function, it won't let me set a value to it.
for example:

```
int func() {
    int* pointer;
    *pointer = 0    //error I get: "Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION"
    return *pointer;
}
```

I get that not letting you set a pointer in the function because if I use a normal int it works:

```
int func() {
    int notAPointer;
    notAPointer = 0;
    return notAPointer;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why that is?

Comment: Because what you basically did was take a pizza cardboard, cut a business card from it, and then drive to what looked like an "address" that happened to be scribbled on that piece of cardboard. And then you tried to ring the doorbell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't assigned any memory for your pointer to point to.

That means that dereferencing the pointer (`*pointer`) causes undefined behavior (like a crash in your case). You need to **initialize** the pointer before dereferencing it:

```
int* pointer = new int;
```

<sub>(And afterwards, `delete pointer;` to not leak the memory. **Always** `delete` everything you get from `new`.)</sub>

---

Also, pointers don't have to point to *dynamically allocated* data (acquired by a call to `new`), you can point to *automatic (stack) variables* too:

```
int func() {
    int valueOnStack = 42;
    int* pointer = &valueOnStack;
    *pointer = 0;
    return *pointer;
}
```

Comment: I agree with zenith, I dont see anything wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you declare `pointer` it is pointing to a completely arbitrary memory location. You can't just write to any old piece of memory.

You need to allocate memory for it first:

```
int* pointer = new int;
*pointer = 0;
```

Or just:

```
int* pointer = new int();
```

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `pointer` is uninitialized and points to a random location in memory when you declare it. It could be pointing into the system stack, or the global variables, or into the program's code space, or into the operating system. When you say `*pointer = 0`;, the program will simply try to write a `0` to whatever random location `pointer` points to.

The program may explode immediately, or may wait half an hour and then explode, or it may subtly corrupt data in another part of your program and you may never realize it. This can make this error very hard to track down. Make sure you initialize all pointers to a valid address before dereferencing them.

Answer (score 0):

`pointer` does not point to anything following `int* pointer;`

So the behaviour of dereferencing it is undefined.

If you'd written

```
int n;
pointer = &n;
```

then you *could* dereference it.

Altenatively, you can allocate memory to it from the *heap*:

```
pointer = new int;
```

But you **must** remember to call `delete pointer;` else you'll leak memory.

Answer (score -1):

This code is completely valid inside a function:

```
int *pointer = 0;
```

BUT, it would be the same as setting a pointer to the NULL macro.

If you try to set another value the compiler is going to complain that there is no valid conversion from 
int to int*:

```
int *pointer = 1;  // Error
```

However, if you want to assign a value to the pointer, follow TartanLlama's answer using *new and delete*. Allocate memory first and then assign a value:

```
int *pointer = new int;
*pointer = 1;  // OK
// delete when appropriate
```